# create an index for aggregating daily data to match periodic data

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, data.table, xts

I have daily measurements `prec.d` and periodic measurements `prec.p`. The periodic measurements (3-12 days apart) are roughly the sum of the daily measurements between the `start` and `end` dates, and I need to compare `prec` in the two data frames. I have so far manually created an index `week` that represents the time span of each periodic measurement, but it would be great to make `week` in a reproducible fashion.

`data.frame` `prec.d`

```
     day  week  prec
6/20/2013   1   0
6/21/2013   1   0
6/22/2013   1   0
6/23/2013   1   0
6/24/2013   1   41.402
6/25/2013   1   2.794
6/26/2013   1   6.096
6/27/2013   2   0.508
6/28/2013   2   0
6/29/2013   2   0
6/30/2013   2   2.54
7/1/2013    2   18.034
7/2/2013    2   4.064
```

And `data.frame` `prec.p`

```
  start         end   week  prec1      prec2        prec3
6/20/2013   6/26/2013   1   50.28   31.78042615 42.76461716
6/27/2013   7/2/2013    2   25.1    15.70964247 20.49507586
```

I would like to create the `week` field automatically, which spans from start to end in `prec.p`.  The I can aggregate by week to make `prec` in both data frames match.

Comment: So far I manually created a factor to represent the time period to be aggregated, but id like this to be reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce YYYYWW field in both weekly and minute data, WW stands for week number, that will give you a common index. For example

```
x <- as.Date(runif(100)*100)
yyyyww <- strftime(x, format="%Y%U")
yyyyww
```

Or take a look at package `quantmod`, if I remember correctly, it has functions for time frame conversion.

Comment: thanks, but unless i'm missing something your example doesn't account for the variable time periods.  I edited my explanation for clarity, and added example data.